# Is this an entire function?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is $f(z)=|z^k|$ [where k is an odd natural number] an entire function?

I can see that for k=1 it is not.(It is not even real differentiable)
But what about let's say k=3?

Comment: It will have Dirac jump in third real derivative at $z=0$. From positive to negative $6$.

Answer (score 2):

The only real valued entire functions are constants as you can see from C - R equations.

Comment: or Liouville. Anyway thanks for the solution, I was trying to show differentiability by definition and got stuck

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $|z^k| = |z|^k$ "should be"
$$
k |z|^{k-1}\;\frac{d}{dz} |z| .
$$
At any point where $|z|\ne 0$, use the fact that $|z|$ is not differentiable to conclude that $|z|^k$ is also not differentiable.